# Angular 2: Generate the route link using functions/ Dynamically generate the routerLink

Tags: angular, router

I want to create a route link dynamically.

I have the html loaded with the page however, i need to use an id in the URL which is available much later.

HTML :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" routerLink="cartoonBoxUrl()" routerLinkActive="active">Add Content to Cartoon Box</a>
```

The link in this routelink contains the id of the cartoon box(/carton-box/1). This id is available after the page loads. Therefore i need a way to create a route link to include this id.

So i believe we can do something like : `routerLink="'cartoon-box/' + id"` but i was hoping to link routerlink to a component function

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer : Done .. please check

Comment: So what's the problem? You can use methods in template expressions just fine.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I caant seem to attach a function to routerLink. Is code correct ?

Comment: its 3 years later but what was the content of your function cartoonBoxByURL()? Or how does it return its value? I am doing same thing but it adds () so my links end up becoming cartoon/(1) instead of cartoon/1?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without `[]` Angular doesn't evaluate the expression and just uses `cartoonBoxUrl()` as literal string.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" [routerLink]="cartoonBoxUrl()" routerLinkActive="active">Add Content to Cartoon Box</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)=cartoonBoxUrl()>Add Content to Cartoon Box</a>
```

in your ts **component.ts** file do

```
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
public ID: any;
constructor(private router: Router){}
cartoonBoxUrl(){
 this.ID = Your LinkId;
 this.router.navigate(['YourRouteLink/', this.ID]);

}
```

Comment: Doing it this way, routerLinkActive gets lost. Gunters answer is the correct way to do it.

Comment: This is useful it you want to open a link to some other place outside of your Angular app.

Comment: How to use `routerLinkActive` in this case?